# Compose ModalBottomSheetState animateTo method is Internal

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to have a button in my modal bottom sheet in order to change the state of bottom sheet to expand whenever the user clicked on it. but `animateTo` method of `ModalBottomSheetState` is internal and we cannot use it.

what am I doing wrong? is there any specific trick for doing this?

Comment: Do you want to open the bottom sheet in half expanded state which contains a button to expand it completely on clicking?

Comment: @Abhimanyu Exactly. that is what I want to do.

Comment: You're not supposed to call `animateTo` manually. Control it via the input state instead.

Comment: I am able to achieve the required state changes without animation, would that work for you? It would not appear smooth.

Comment: @Abhimanyu No actually I need it with a smooth animation. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Jorn input state? which input state you mean? there are only show and hide methods as public ones

Comment: Another option is to animate the container of the bottom sheet. But then it may not work with swipe gestures as expected. Bottom sheet handling is made very complicated in Compose by hiding a lot of required info and actions. 

Comment: @Abhimanyu Thank you for your nice solution. Currently I solved it with copying the content of ModalBottomSheet and changing the `animateTo` method to non internal. But I'm looking forward for a standard solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun ModalBottomSheetSample() {

    val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = state,
        sheetContent = {
         BottomSheetContent{
           scope.launch {
              state.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
          }
  }
     
        }
    )
}
@Composable
fun BottomSheetContent(
  onButtonClick : () -> Unit
) {
  Button( onClick = onButtonClick ){

}
}
```

Comment: In newer versions of compose, animate methods are not available anymore.

Comment: Is it also made internal in the BottomSheetScaffold?

Comment: I don't see the method in `bottomSheetScaffoldState` as well.